# how to add webrtc aec in pjsip，running on Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, webrtc, pjsip, aec

i dont konw how build webrtc aec in pjsip，I don't want to download all the code for webrtc, just the aec section，embed cpu is imx6ul，Please give me some guidance, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

They are both written in C so migration of the WebRTC module and make it compiable should be easy.

You should take advantage of pjsip's Audio Manipulation Algorithms module. It allows you to apply algos on the processing audio sample frames.
https://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__FRAME__OP.htm

For the AEC, make sure you have access to the loopback channel on the codec. (Samples from playing speaker).

Steps:

- Create a New Audio Manipulation Algorithms Module
- Gain access to audio playback/capture signals with pjmedia
- Migrate WebRTC AEC Module
- Reroute the signal processing pipeline and enabling the AEC Algorithms module